# Importing dummy data at a google analytics account

Tags: google-analytics

I'm preparing a presentation for my coworkers on Google Analytics, and would like to have a fake account, with some data on it. I already have an account with more than 2 years data, which I could use as a starting point, but would have to mask some e-commerce numbers, since it is confidential.

Is there a way to export my data, modify a few things on it and import it again on this new fake account? Or any other smart strategy?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export data from GA in a way that easily allows re-import (for one thing the client id would be missing which is needed to sort pageviews into  sessions)

What I did in a similar situation was to look at  the d[ocumentation for the Google Analytics measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters). I then created a php script that started with a nummer of array with example values for necessary fields - dummy client ids, pagenames, urls, ip addresses to provide geo information etc. The PHP script would shuffle the values to generate random pageviews and send them via curl to the Google Analytics endpoint. Then I put this up on a server and had a cronjob run it every minute or so for a few days.

That's fairly simple -  I didn't generate e-commerce transactions, that would be a bit more work since a transaction had multiple send events plus you'd need a realistic looking checkout funnel. But since I defined all the input myself the data was safe and could not possibly include real data.